# usage of the 'but-a' phrase

Tags: phrases

I've heard the use of 'but a' like this:

1. I am but a common man.
2. He is but a clever dog.

I'd expected something like this:
3. I am anything but not a common man
4. He is nothing but a common dog.

*(Side question, what are the words anything, nothing in the sentence called?)*
In the absence of words like anything, nothing, I'm unable to make sense of the sentences. Does it imply that he is a common man or not? Same for the dog, clever or not. What does the phrase `but a` imply here? Please tell me about it's usage.

Comment: First, I think that both sentences 1. and 2. have "nothing" dropped in order to make its meaning someway poetic. *I am [nothing] but a common man*"; the meaning of "but" in your sentences is *"just, only"*.

Comment: Avoid the usage in your first two examples - it's dated / poetic, bordering on archaic. We use ***just*** or ***only*** (or feasibly ***simply, merely, purely,...***) in such contexts today. The "negative polarity" examples 3 & 4, where ***but*** effectively means ***except***, are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rare, and dated. (so normally a learner should not use this).

It has much the same meaning as "merely", or "no more than" and is used in humble expression when speaking about oneself:

> I'm merely common man, and nothing more.

So it does mean "I am a common man".

So when applied to others, it is disparaging. A clever dog is still much less clever than the stupidest human.

> You are no better than a clever dog.

"Anything" is an adverb in your sentence

Comment: can you explain the example no. 2: "You are no better than a clever dog. " shouldn't it be:  "He is merely a clever dog" acc. to explanation no. 1?

Comment: "no better than" could be called as a fixed expression, as in: You are no friend of mine.

Comment: @JamesK , how is it an adverb? There are no verbs in the sentence.... can you please explain

Comment: it is an adjucnt to the adverb "but".  There is a verb, the verb is "is".  (in English, the copula is a verb)

Answer (score 0):

"but a" is indeed an idiom meaning "nothing but a."

Comment: I agree. I would also say that the usage is somewhat stylized and archaic, the sort of thing one finds in early 20th-century novels as opposed to current everyday speech, at least in the US.